# Cross reference columns from two pandas DFs. If a match is found, fill information from one DF to the other

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to cross reference one DF which has a column of addresses and postcodes, with another DF which has addresses and an totally empty column which is to accept postcodes. If addresses match beween df1 and df2, df2 should accept the postcode form df1.

> df1
>
> ```
>    Address         PostCode 
>
>      A              1  
>
>      B              2
>
>      C              3
>
>      D              4
> ```
>
> df2
>
> ```
>    Address         PostCode 
>
>      A       
>
>      R     
>
>      C   
>
>      Z
> ```

The goal I would like to achieve is that df2 should be:

> df2
>
> ```
>    Address         PostCode 
>      A              1 
>
>      R              NaN
>
>      C              3
>
>      Z              Nan
> ```

I am a bit lost on this one, I have tried joining, merging, booleans, using 'isin' and other commands. I cannot seem to figure this one out. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: how about `df2.PostCode= df2.Address.map(dict(zip(df1.Address,df1.PostCode)))`?

Comment: Is your `df1.Postcode` a column of `NaN`?

Comment: df1 postcode are ints. @user3483203

Comment: Unfortunately this did not work but nice thinking @anky_91

Comment: @CiaranOBrien i dont understand, this works for the given example?

Comment: @anky_91 It doesn't seem to work for me. Address is actually a string, so perhaps this is a problem

Comment: @CiaranOBrien so `df2.Address.map(dict(zip(df1.Address,df1.PostCode.astype(str))))` ? if not what is th error you're getting, how is it not working? please tell us more

Answer (score 0):

If you're okay with PostCode having dtype=object

```
>>> df1
  Address  PostCode
0       A         1
1       B         2
2       C         3
3       D         4
>>> df2
  Address PostCode
0       A
1       R
2       C
3       Z
>>> df3 = df2.merge(df1, on='Address', how='left')
>>> df3['PostCode'] = df3.PostCode_y.combine_first(df3.PostCode_x)
>>> df3
  Address PostCode_x  PostCode_y PostCode
0       A                    1.0        1
1       R                    NaN
2       C                    3.0        3
3       Z                    NaN
>>> df3[['Address', 'PostCode']]
  Address PostCode
0       A        1
1       R
2       C        3
3       Z
```

Alternatively you can do this but it will change PostCode to have dtype=float64 in order to handle the NaN. You can always fix the data types later.

```
>>> df2.Address.map(df1.set_index('Address').PostCode)
0    1.0
1    NaN
2    3.0
3    NaN
Name: Address, dtype: float64
```

Note that using df1.set_index('Address').PostCode is an indexed series. You could get the same effect if you had a dictionary of Address to PostCodes.

Comment: Reindexing is not possible as some addresses are duplicates so it is throwing me an error. However creating a new df3 seems to work. @Orenshi